# How to download files from AWS S3 bucket to springboot app on openshift?

Tags: amazon-s3, download, connection, openshift, port

My Spring Boot application is going to be deployed on Openshift and from my application i need to  download  files from AWS S3 bucket on other n/w.
What is the best way to connect to S3 and get the files. I am trying to use AmazonS3 client. Do i need to do configurations at the openshift infra level? Is there any other way with which we can download the files?

Comment: Where your openshift is deployed ? is it also in AWS and the same account in which your S3 is located?

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggested method using IAM roles.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/a-guide-to-locally-testing-containers-with-amazon-ecs-local-endpoints-and-docker-compose/

Scenario: Testing using Task IAM Role credentials
The endpoints container image can also vend credentials from an IAM Role; this allows you to test your application locally using a Task IAM Role.

NOTE: You should not use your production Task IAM Role locally. Instead, create a separate testing role, with equivalent permissions scoped to testing resources. Modifying the trust boundary of a production role will expand its scope.

In order to use a Task IAM Role locally, you must modify its trust policy. First, get the ARN of the IAM user defined by your default AWS CLI Profile (replace default with a different Profile name if needed):

aws --profile default sts get-caller-identity

Then modify your Task IAM Role so that its trust policy includes the following statement. You can find instructions for modifying IAM Roles in the IAM Documentation.

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": <ARN of the user found with get-caller-identity>
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
```

To use your Task IAM Role in your docker compose file for local testing, simply change the value of the AWS container credentials relative URI environment variable on your application container:

AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI: "/role/"

For example, if your role is named ecs_task_role, then the environment variable should be set to "/role/ecs_task_role". That is all that is required; the ecs-local-endpoints container will now vend credentials obtained from assuming the task role. You can use this to validate that the permissions set on your Task IAM Role are sufficient to run your application.